# combining tap event of 3 buttons with rxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have 3 buttons

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var editGeomButton: UIButton! // 1
@IBOutlet weak var editDataButton: UIButton! // 2
@IBOutlet weak var deleteDataButton: UIButton! // 3
```

On click of any of this buttons I want below method to be called. With the proper numbers.

```swift
func didTap() -> Observable<Int> {

}

didTap().subscribe(onNext: { (tag) in
    switch tag {
    case 1:
        print("Did tap Edit Geom")
    case 2:
        print("Did tap Edit Data")
    case 3:
        print("Did tap Delete geom")
    default:
        print("Invalid tap")
    }
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Please help with the code to write in didTap method using Observable? I think this can be achieved using combine operator. But I don't understand how to code this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use an enum instead to avoid the default case:

```
enum Actions {
  case editGeom
  case editData
  case deleteGeom
}

Observable.merge(
  editGeomButton.rx.tap.map { _ in Actions.editGeom },
  editDataButton.rx.tap.map { _ in Actions.editData },
  deleteDataButton.rx.tap.map { _ in Actions.deleteGeom }
).subscribe(onNext: {
  switch $0 {
  case .editGeom:
    print("Did tap Edit Geom")
  case .editData:
    print("Did tap Edit Data")
  case .deleteGeom:
    print("Did tap Delete geom")
  }
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Basically, it's just mapping each tap to a value before merging them together.

Comment: Great pattern using Action types, which feels like Redux.